# Pyspark remove parts of URL using regex in column

Tags: pyspark

I would like to get this result in pyspark. What I have is Request URL column

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can execute twice and get the desired results

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import F

df = df.withColumn(
            "full_url", F.regexp_extract(F.col("request_url"), "^GET ([^? ]*)", 1)
        )

df = df.withColumn(
            "short_url", F.regexp_extract(F.col("request_url"), "^GET ([^.]*)[.]", 1)
        )
```